# Do any set theories have cardinalities that are not realized by any ordinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm just starting to a little bit here and there about large cardinals. I have a basic question, namely, how do we know that every *cardinality* is realized by an ordinal?

One possible definition of an ordinal is a transitive set on which $\in$ is trichotomous. (I'm not sure which definition is most natural for non-well-founded set theories).

Cardinality can be defined in terms of the existence of injections (which gives us a relation $\le$). By picking the least ordinal with a given cardinality, we get the [von Neumann cardinal assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment).

How do we know, however, that every cardinality has at least one ordinal that realizes it?

Also, are there any set theories where that is not true?

Comment: The Axiom of Choice is equivalent to well-ordering of all sets, which in turn amounts to every cardinal being "realized" by an ordinal.

Comment: What's a better term than "realized"? "Inhabited" also doesn't seem right.

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking whether all sets can be well-ordered (since via Replacement every well-orderable set is in bijection with an ordinal). This is [equivalent to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem) the axiom of choice - so $\mathsf{ZFC}$ thinks that every cardinality is realized by an ordinal (to use your language), $\mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$ thinks the opposite, and $\mathsf{ZF}$ is undecided on the issue. (I'm putting this as a comment as opposed to an answer since I'm sure this is a duplicate.)

Comment: There are set theories in which the Axiom of Choice doesn't hold, so there we would have cardinalities for which well-ordering is impossible. E.G.: In Quine's New Foundations the Axiom of Choice is provably false.

Comment: How about "represented".